# AJAX and Node JS : receiving empty data in my server

Tags: node.js, ajax

I'm trying to make a `POST` request to my node JS server, I tried with `Postman` and it's works fine but when I use AJAX I got an empty data in the server, I tried to use `contentType: "application/json"` but I got this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCVSk.png)
this is AJAX code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/comment",
    data: {
        "email": "admin@gmail.com",
        "contenu": "Hello",
        "id_article": 1653817160
    },
    success: function (data2) {
        console.log(data2)
    }
})
```

Comment: you should able `cors` for you server https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to CORS setup on the NodeJS server. Basically your server has this policy that every request needs to be made from the same domain.

Here is explained how CORS works:
https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Be careful, it's important to have this in mind:

> WARNING: Using Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * can make your
> API/website vulnerable to cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks.
> Make certain you understand the risks before using this code.

Install the CORS package from npm or yarn and follow this code sample:

```js
Install the CORS package from npm or yarn and follow this code sample:
  const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');

require('dotenv').config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(cors());
```

Hope it will help you :)